# How does google docs/drive's instant edit work?

Tags: ajax

If you have ever used google docs/google drive, they have a feature where two users can simutaneously edit a document and the document updates it live, as if you had MS Word open but with two mouse and two keyboards.

I'm interested as to how this actually works. I'm pretty sure they don't write to a DB and check it every second, so what are the mechanics behind it? Could you explain the basic concept as to how they do this?

PS: I'm not sure what to tag this with, any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time a user makes a change to an open document or navigates around it, an asynchronous request is made to Google Docs informing them of this. The GDoc server then uses the HTTP Comet request opened by other clients to inform them of that user's actions.

Ref: [Read about Comet at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET you can achieve this by creating a WCF REST service on the server side, and JSON on the client side.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) is an excellent example of setting up a WCF REST service:

Connecting the client is the easy part. Here is an example of how you would approach it with JQuery:

```
    function GetData()
    {            

        var URL = 'http://localhost:50164/RestServiceImpl.svc/json4'; //REPLACE this with the URL to your WCF service
        $.getJSON(URL, function (data) { ShowResult(data); });           

    }            

    function ShowResult(data)
    {
        $('#tblMyTable').dataTable(data); //USING the dataTable plugin for jquery download at: http://datatables.net/
    }
```

Good luck!